# Immediately-Invoked setTimeOut expression

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

In the following code, I have used IIFE to immediately execute the closure during the current iteration of the loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log('Im in counter ' + i);
  (function() {
    var num = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(num);
    },0);
  })();
};
```

The above code prints the output as follows:
Im in counter 0
Im in counter 1
Im in counter 2
0
1
2

If the closure is immediately invoked on current iteration, then the following output is what expected rather than the actual output given above. Can anyone explain the reason for this strange behavior of IIFE in for-loop?
Im in counter 0
0
Im in counter 1
1
Im in counter 2
2

Comment: You're missing the 2nd parameter to `setTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout` queues a function to run at some point in the future.  With a timeout of `0`, that queues it *after* the currently running code/function has finished.  The browser will finish the function, possibly run some other events/code then run your timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a function to `setTimeout` puts it in a queue. It will fire when:

- The time (you didn't specify one, but there is a minimum time that gets applied) has run out **and**
- The event loop isn't busy running another function

So you enter the loop. Log the value. Put a function on the setTimeout queue. Then repeat.

Eventually you get to the end of the loop. The function finishes. Shortly therefore the timer runs out and the setTimeout function executes. The the next one does. And so on.

Comment: But this happens even without using IIFE. doesn't it?

Comment: @Prem — Yes, the only difference the IIFE makes is to stop `num` being a global (but `num` is pointless since you can use `i` directly)

Answer (score 1):

The below answer is right. The setTimeout function gets executed instantly (you can verifiy this by writing the return of setTimeout, which is an identifier of the timer). Instead of using a loop, just verifiy the value each time the function you passed to setTimeout gets executed. Take a look at this code:

```
  var num = 3;

function a(x) {
  setTimeout(function c() {
    console.log(x);
    x++;
    if (x<= num) a(x);
  },1000);
}

a(0);
```

a is called with an initial value of 0. This set ups a timeout to log that value. In that function, if the numbers is less than the num variable it calls itself again.